# Python Azure Functions - how to set the database name dynamically?

Tags: python, binding, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-durable-functions

In an Azure Function, I have the following binding. I need to find a way to assign the `databaseName` dynamically, because using `myDatabaseName` does not work, as in my organisation, the database name has the environment tag attached. So, I need to have:

- myDatabaseName-DEV
- myDatabaseName-UAT
- myDatabaseName-PRD

Hence, I need to create the database name dynamically depending on the environment I'm in. Is this even possible? And if not, what's the best workaround for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions support binding expressions: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns

You can use `%databaseName%` as your `databaseName` for example as value and have that value replaced dynamically on runtime based on the Function Configuration.

Comment: And where would that `databaseName` come from?

Comment: As per the documentation in the link, anything defined between the `%` (ie `%name_of_config%`) can be defined in the Functions App Configuration or environment variables and will be replaced on runtime. This is not particular to Cosmos DB but it's how Function bindings work in general.